# javascript + css basic animation + functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm aware of all the awesomeness about jQuery and everything... However I'm still very weak with javascript and feel to mess around with it and get more confident..

What I'm Trying to achieve:

> onmouseout sub.style = "display:none"; // my way did not work so i used a method so i used document.onclick (temporarily)
>   menuOver.onmouseover // add a simple css or js effect

**css**

```
#menuOver
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    width:110px;
    color:white;
    z-index: 10;
}

#sub
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 190px;
    width:110px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transition-duration: .25s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .25s;
    -o-transition-duration: .25s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .25s;
    transition-duration: .25s;

    /* border: solid #444 1px; */
}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(document.readyState == "complete")
    {



        var sub                 = document.getElementById("sub");
        var menuOver            = document.getElementById("menuOver");
        var container           = document.getElementById("container"); //for later use

        menuOver.onmouseover = function()
        {
            menuOver.style       = "display:none";
            sub.style            =   "display:block;top:40px;";
            sub.innerHTML        =  "<a href='#'>profile</a></span>";
            sub.innerHTML       += "<br />";
            sub.innerHTML       += "<span><a href='?cmd=logout'>logout</a></span>";
            //alert("menuOver"); //Debugging Purpose 
        }

        document.onclick = function()
        {
            //hide menu
            sub.style = "display:none";

            //activate Hover Menu
            menuOver.style   = "display:block";;

            //alert("Outside"); //Debugging Purpose 
        }   
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="holder" class="pull-right"><!-- this is a bootstrap class -->
    <div id="menuOver"></div>
    <div id="sub"></div>
</div>
```

Again I'm only *coding to learn* here...
Any advices and/or tutorials to get me more familiar with the whole workout is extremely appreciated..

Comment: that does not work, there is not enough jQuery))

Comment: Use css `#menuOver:hover` to add mouse_over/hover effect

Comment: I think you should add the html stuff inside the sub and just hide it. So instead of javascript put the html in the html document.

Comment: Also I don't think javascript allows usage of `style` the way you do. You should use `sub.style.display = "none";` instead (here is a working code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/auzsd)

Comment: ** I'm using javascript to get familiar with it **

Comment: [-1 not enough JQuery](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: Gasim 

I thought the same till i tried it.. you can even add a couple of them followed by ; (worked for me at least)

Comment: What is thé question ?

Comment: Singe31

>What I'm Trying to achieve:

    onmouseout sub.style = "display:none"; // my way did not work so i used a method so i used document.onclick (temporarily) menuOver.onmouseover // add a simple css or js effect